# Stopping a CentOS 7 systemd service is stopping multiple targets

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to manage multiple service instances with systemctl.  I have two files in /etc/systemd/system:

```
cat FOO@.service

[Unit]
Description="FOO instance #%i"
PartOf=FOO.target
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=pacemaker.service
After=network.target network-online.target pacemaker.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=300
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
Type=forking
User=myuser
Group=mygrp
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/StartFOO.sh -s %i -f no
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/StopFOO.sh  -s %i
LimitNOFILE=16384
LimitNPROC=514340
LimitCORE=infinity
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description=FOO Workers
Requires=FOO@1001.service FOO@1002.service FOO@1003.service FOO@1004.service FOO@1005.service FOO@1006.service FOO@1007.service FOO@1008.service FOO@1009.service FOO@1011.service FOO@1012.service FOO@1013.service FOO@1014.service FOO@1015.service FOO@1016.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

All 16 services stop and start perfectly when the server reboots, or by running systemctl start FOO@1001.service systemctl stop FOO@1001.service However after I reboot the server, if I stop one service it stops them all. If I then restart all of the services they all start and stop normally, one at a time. Until the next server reboot.

The solution was to move "PartOf" from the [Unit] to the [Install] section in FOO@.service

Comment: For us to help you, you need to tell us what problem you're trying to solve and how the things you've tried (i.e. the two files) did not work :)

Comment: @ex_submariner updates to your post should be in an [edit] not in a comment. I've incorporated your first comment, but wanted to make you aware of how SE works in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what command you're using to try to stop a single process?

Comment: The command to stop instance 1001 for example is

systemctl stop FOO@1001.service